# Share context between views in Django?

Tags: python, django, view

I have 3 views for very similar views and templates.

My code is becoming repetitive and it doesn't seem to be following Django **DRY** approach.

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def registrations_check1_detail(request, registration_pk):

    registration = get_object_or_404(Registration, pk=registration_pk)

    costumer_profile_form = forms.CostumerProfileForm()

    # THIS CONTEXT IS REPEATED ACROSS  MANY OF MY VIEWS
    request_context = {
        'registration': registration,
        'status': Registration.STATUS_CHOICES,
        'costumer_profile_form': costumer_profile_form,
        'duration_form':  pf.DurationForm(),
        'REG_DURATION_CHOICES'  : Duration.REG_DURATION_CHOICES,
        'EXT_DURATION_CHOICES'  : Duration.EXT_DURATION_CHOICES,
        'is_editable': editable_fields_perm(request.user, registration)
    }

    return render(request, 'profiles/registrations_check1_detail.html', request_context)

@login_required
def finance_review_detail(request, registration_pk):

    costumer_profile_form = forms.CostumerProfileForm()

    registration = get_object_or_404(Registration, pk=registration_pk)

    request_context = {
        'registration': registration,
        'costumer_profile_form': costumer_profile_form,
        'duration_form':  pf.DurationForm(),
        'REG_DURATION_CHOICES'  : Duration.REG_DURATION_CHOICES,
        'EXT_DURATION_CHOICES'  : Duration.EXT_DURATION_CHOICES,
        'is_editable': editable_fields_perm(request.user, registration)
    }

    return render(request, 'profiles/finance_review_detail.html', request_context)
```

Which is the proper way to handle this?

**Edit**

Following Shang Wang's advice this is how it looks now:

```
@login_required
def registration_detail(request, registration_pk):

    request_context = _registration_context(registration_pk, request.user)

    return render(request, 'profiles/registration_detail.html', request_context)
```

Comment: There are class based views, can have one generic view and then subclass it or use mixins https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal, but the solution is really trivial, you could extract them into a function and only pass in the parameters that it needs to produce the result like `costumer_profile_form`, `registration` in this case. Then you call the function and that should be it.